# PayPal Express Checkout MVC C# sample code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, nvp

I'm developing an asp.net MVC4 site which will accept payment via paypal. Has anyone seen any C# samples for express checkout using NVP because I didn't find the supplied Java or PHP examples that useful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah I actually put together a C# library just for this, including a working ASP.NET MVC3 sample site you can use for testing.

You can get the source from here;
https://bitbucket.org/jhelmink/paypalexpresscheckoutmvc

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have also published a [PayPal Express Checkout SDK](https://github.com/daishisystems/Daishi.PaySharp), complete with Unit Tests, working examples, Test Harness, and extensive documentation.

Comment: I tried the above and the official paypal sdk and both failed with 10002 authorization errors. It wasn't until I tried your sample that instructed me to include my merchant ID that I found out why nothing worked before.  Thanks!